# How to build hierarchy paths with hierarchical subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery, connect-by

**EDIT: I provided additinal information by introducing *location* entity to make it clear why I tried to use subqueries**

In oracle 11g database I have hierarchical structured table of *elements* which will eventually contain few millions of rows. Each row has indexed foreign key that points to its parent and no cycles are allowed. *Element* also has name and type. Besides that, there is another entity - *location*, which is similar to *element* (hierarchical, has foreign key that points to parent + name). Top *element* (root of you will) can be in *location* (they are connected by *LocationId*). So there are 2 entities:

**Location:**

- Id [NUMBER(9,0), PK]
- ParentId [NUMBER(9,0), FK]
- Name [VARCHAR2(200)]

**Element:**

- Id [NUMBER(9,0), PK]
- LocationId [NUMBER(9,0), FK]
- ParentId [NUMBER(9,0), FK]
- TypeId [NUMBER(9,0), FK]
- Name [VARCHAR2(200)]

Now lets say tables contain following data for example:

**Location:**

```
Id   | ParentId | Name
----------------------------------
100  |   null   | TopLocation
101  |   100    | Level1Location
102  |   101    | Level2Location
```

**Element:**

```
Id | LocationId | ParentId | TypeId | Name
----------------------------------------------------
1  |    102     |   null   |    10  | TopParent
2  |   null     |     1    |    11  | Level1Child
3  |   null     |     2    |    11  | Level2Child
```

What I have to do is write query for *elements*, which besides basic 4 *element* columns also returns full paths of parent ids, names and type ids + full path of top *element*  *location* ids and names. So if I fetched *element* with Id 3 (this condition can also be complex by multiple columns which are not specified here) query would have to return this:

```
Id | ParentId | TypeId | Name        | IdsPath | TypeIdsPath | NamesPath                           | LocIdsPath   | LocNamesPath
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  |    2     |    11  | Level2Child | /3/2/1  |   /11/11/10 |  /Level2Child/Level1Child/TopParent | /102/101/100 | /Level2Location/Level1Location/TopLocation
```

First I wrote [oracle hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) which returns desired paths for *location* and *element*

**Location**

```
select
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Id, '/') IdsPath,
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Name, '/') NamesPath
from 
    loc
where
     connect_by_isleaf = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ParentId = e.Id
start with Id = 102
```

**Element**

```
select
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Id, '/') IdsPath,
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(TypeId, '/') TypeIdsPath,
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Name, '/') NamesPath
from 
    ele
where
     connect_by_isleaf = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ParentId = e.Id
start with Id = 3
```

The problems started when I wanted to use these queries as subqueries joined in basic select - one cannot replace *start with* condition with join condition because hierarchical queries than do full table scans:

```
select
    e.*,
    elePath.IdsPath,
    elePath.TypeIdsPath,
    elePath.NamesPath,
    locPath.IdsPath as LocIdsPath,
    locPath.NamesPath as LocNamesPath
from
    ele e
    left join (
        --full table scan!
        select
            CONNECT_BY_ROOT(Id) Id,
            Id as TopEleId,
            SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Id, '/') IdsPath,
            SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(TypeId, '/') TypeIdsPath,
            SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Name, '/') NamesPath
        from ele
        where
             connect_by_isleaf = 1
        CONNECT BY PRIOR ParentId = e.Id
    ) elePath on elePath.Id = e.Id
    left join (
        --full table scan!
        select
            CONNECT_BY_ROOT(Id) Id,
            SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Id, '/') IdsPath,
            SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Name, '/') NamesPath
        from loc
        where
             connect_by_isleaf = 1
        CONNECT BY PRIOR ParentId = e.Id
    ) locPath on locPath.Id = elePath.TopEleId
where
    e.Id = 3
```

I also cant do [scalar subquery](http://sql-plsql.blogspot.com/2009/03/sql-scalar-subquery.html) since query has to return multiple paths, not just one. Any suggestions? Am I even going in right direction or should I rather add a few fields to element table and cache all paths I need? (they will not be frequently updated)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You traverse hierarchical structure in reverse direction, simply use `connect_by_root()` operator to get column values of the root row.

```
clear screen;
column IdPath format a11;
column TypeIdPathformat a11
column NamePath format a35;

with t1(id1, parent_id, type_id, Name1) as(
  select 1, null, 10, 'TopParent' from dual union all
  select 2, 1   , 11, 'Level1Child' from dual union all
  select 3, 2   , 11, 'Level2Child' from dual
)
select connect_by_root(id1)                as id1
     , connect_by_root(parent_id)          as ParentId
     , connect_by_root(type_id)            as Typeid
     , connect_by_root(name1)              as name1
     , sys_connect_by_path(id1, '/')       as IdPath
     , sys_connect_by_path(type_id, '/')   as TypeIdPath
     , sys_connect_by_path(name1, '/')     as NamePath 
 from t1
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with id1 = 3
connect by id1 = prior parent_id
```

Result:

```
 id1 ParentId TypeId  Name1        IdPath  TypeIdPath NamePath                         
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------       
 3        2      11   Level2Child /3/2/1  /11/11/10  /Level2Child/Level1Child/TopParent
```

---

**Edit #1**

One way to get the desired output is to use scalar sub-query:

```
with Locations(Id1, ParentId, Name1) as(
  select 100,  null, 'TopLocation' from dual union all
  select 101,  100 , 'Level1Location' from dual union all
  select 102,  101 , 'Level2Location' from dual
),
elements(id1, LocationId, parent_id, type_id, Name1) as(
  select 1, 102,  null, 10, 'TopParent' from dual union all
  select 2, null, 1   , 11, 'Level1Child' from dual union all
  select 3, null, 2   , 11, 'Level2Child' from dual
)
select e.*
     , (select sys_connect_by_path(l.id1, '/')
          from locations l
          where connect_by_isleaf = 1
          start with l.id1 = e.locationid
          connect by l.id1 = prior parentid)        as LocIdPath
     , (select sys_connect_by_path(l.name1, '/')
          from locations l
          where connect_by_isleaf = 1
          start with l.id1 = e.locationid
          connect by l.id1 = prior parentid)        as LocNamePath
  from ( select connect_by_root(id1)                as id1
              , connect_by_root(parent_id)          as ParentId
              , connect_by_root(type_id)            as Typeid
              , connect_by_root(name1)              as name1
              , sys_connect_by_path(id1, '/')       as IdPath
              , sys_connect_by_path(type_id, '/')   as TypeIdPath
              , sys_connect_by_path(name1, '/')     as NamePath  
              , locationid
          from elements
         where connect_by_isleaf = 1
         start with id1 = 3
       connect by id1 = prior parent_id ) e
```

Result:

```
ID1   PARENTID     TYPEID NAME1       IDPATH      TYPEIDPATH  NAMEPATH                            LOCATIONID LOCIDPATH     LOCNAMEPATH                               
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------------------- ---------- ------------- -------------------------------------------
  3          2         11 Level2Child /3/2/1      /11/11/10   /Level2Child/Level1Child/TopParent         102 /102/101/100  /Level2Location/Level1Location/TopLocation
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer, I have thought of that but maybe this example is too simple - In actual case I have to get paths for current entity (element in this case) + few entities that are related to the element by foreign keys - e.g. every element has also foreign key LocationId and locations are also hierarchically structured - so I also need those paths and thats why I asked how to do it with subquery

Comment: @PavleGartner Then you need to provide more information - sample of master\detail data and want exact output you are after. It can be done in sub-query if such a need arises, but more accurate information is needed. In your example you are left outer joining result-set returned by the in-line view to the table that in-line view is based. There no `LocationId` column as well as table that contains that column being mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the effort - I added concept of location to original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, that could work - do you maybe know how would corelated subqueries for location work performance wise - is optimiser smart enough not to walk the hierarchy twice in your query?

Comment: @PavleGartner In fact, because of backward traversing of hierarchical structure, the `Locations` table will be, in this, situation, accessed four times(extra nested loops will be required), and `Elements` table will be accessed twice. But there should not be any major performance penalties if there are appropriate indexes created. Create an index on foreign key if there isn't one.